# Xamarin.forms iOS WkWebView runs in background

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have application with EmbedIO webserver and angular code in WebView with WkWebViewRenderer. In Angular code is polling function.

When app goes to background `DidEnterBackground` is called and I dispose webserver, but webview still runs. How can I pause webview with Angular to stop polling when this event is fired and start it again when app goes to foreground again?

Comment: Hard to say, without seeing your code. Maybe you can do it in your own custom renderer, as in [Customizing a WebView - Create the custom renderer on iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview#create-the-custom-renderer-on-ios). You'll also need a [WKScriptMessageHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/webkit.wkscriptmessagehandler?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12), so you have a way to communicate with web page. OR might be easier to have `DidEnterBackground` tell your wkwebview custom renderer to `Dispose`.

Comment: But ill lose actual state of angular app, or not?

Comment: If you Dispose, yes that would lose state. Just wanted you to be aware that is one way to go.

Comment: Yup, but I dont want to lose it.. or find some way how to save it

Comment: try to comment out "  ((HybridWebView)Element).Cleanup();" in dispose method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've came up with solution for someones interest I use AppShell for navigation in my app..

Here is my EmbedIO webserver helper class:

```
public  class WebServerHelper
{
    private static readonly Lazy<WebServerHelper> lazy = new(() => new WebServerHelper());

    public static WebServerHelper Instance => lazy.Value;

    private CancellationTokenSource _cts;
    private WebServer _webServer = null;

    public void Run()
    {
        if(_webServer == null)
        Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
        {
            using (_cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
            using (_webServer = CreateWebServer())
            {
                await _webServer.RunAsync(_cts.Token);
            }                
        });
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _cts.Cancel();
        _cts = null;
        _webServer = null;
    }

    private WebServer CreateWebServer()
    {
        var server =  new WebServer(o => o
            .WithUrlPrefix($"http://localhost:8080")
            .WithMode(HttpListenerMode.EmbedIO))
        .WithCors()
        .WithLocalSessionManager()
        .WithWebApi("/api", m => m
            .WithController<TestController>()
            ...
            .WithController<SystemController>())
        .WithModule(new ActionModule("/", HttpVerbs.Any,
            ctx => ctx.SendDataAsync(new { Message = "Error" })));

        Trace.TraceInformation($"WebApi started on port: 8080");

        server.OnUnhandledException += (s, e) => { Trace.TraceInformation("Unhadled Exception occured"); return Task.CompletedTask; };
        server.OnHttpException += (s, e) => { Trace.TraceInformation("Http exception occured"); return Task.CompletedTask; };

        return server;
    }
}
```

Than I have Hybrid web view created as is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview)

And it all works in AppDelegate like:

```
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        Forms.Init();

        WebServerHelper.Instance.Run();

        ...

        LoadApplication(new App());

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }

    public override void WillTerminate(UIApplication application)
    {
        application.Dispose();
        base.WillTerminate(application);
    }

    [Export("applicationWillEnterForeground:")]
    public override void WillEnterForeground(UIApplication application)
    {
        //TODO: handle situation when user goes foreground (eg. double tap on start button and turn camera on)
        WebServerHelper.Instance.Run();

        ((WKWebView)((HybridWebView)((WebContainer)((IShellSectionController)Shell.Current?.CurrentItem?.CurrentItem)?.PresentedPage).Content).GetRenderer().NativeView).GoForward();
    }

    [Export("applicationDidEnterBackground:")]
    public override void DidEnterBackground (UIApplication application)
    {
        ((WKWebView)((HybridWebView)((WebContainer)((IShellSectionController)Shell.Current?.CurrentItem?.CurrentItem)?.PresentedPage).Content).GetRenderer().NativeView).GoBack();

        //In background task cancelation token is called dispose of webserver.
        //This step obtain aditional (aprox.) 25 seconds to finish all ongoing operations.
        application.BeginBackgroundTask(() => {
            WebServerHelper.Instance.Stop();
        });
    }
```